# Sub links extract from webpage in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've been trying to write my first extension for chrome. I want this extension to be able to get all the links with a specific format in a webpage and retrieve a certain link from every link's webpage found in the main webpage.

I think the problem might be in the message passing, can you receive a message that will start a set of commands that will trigger another message you want to receive?

manifest.json :

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "TAU Down",
  "description": "This extension downloads whole courses from TAU Moodle website",
  "version": "1.0",

  "permissions": [
    "http://moodle.tau.ac.il/", "downloads", "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

popup.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script src='popup.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<button id=download0>Download All!</button>
<table id=links>
  <tr>
    <th><input type=checkbox checked id=toggle_all></th>
    <th align=left>URL</th>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id=download1>Download All!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

popup.js :

```
// Copyright (c) 2012 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

// This extension demonstrates using chrome.downloads.download() to
// download URLs.

var allLinks = [];
var visibleLinks = [];
var count = 0;

// Display all visible links.
function showLinks() {
  var linksTable = document.getElementById('links');
  while (linksTable.children.length > 1) {
    linksTable.removeChild(linksTable.children[linksTable.children.length - 1])
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < visibleLinks.length; ++i) {
    var row = document.createElement('tr');
    var col0 = document.createElement('td');
    var col1 = document.createElement('td');
    var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
    checkbox.checked = true;
    checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
    checkbox.id = 'check' + i;
    col0.appendChild(checkbox);
    col1.innerText = visibleLinks[i];
    col1.style.whiteSpace = 'nowrap';
    col1.onclick = function() {
      checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked;
    }
    row.appendChild(col0);
    row.appendChild(col1);
    linksTable.appendChild(row);
  }
}

// Toggle the checked state of all visible links.
function toggleAll() {
  var checked = document.getElementById('toggle_all').checked;
  for (var i = 0; i < visibleLinks.length; ++i) {
    document.getElementById('check' + i).checked = checked;
  }
}

// Download all visible checked links.
function downloadCheckedLinks() {
  for (var i = 0; i < visibleLinks.length; ++i) {
    if (document.getElementById('check' + i).checked) {
      chrome.downloads.download({url: visibleLinks[i]},
                                             function(id) {
      });
    }
  }
  window.close();
}

// Re-filter allLinks into visibleLinks and reshow visibleLinks.
function filterLinks() {
  if (count == 0){
  var filterValue = "moodle tau view resource";}
  else{
  var filterValue = "mod_resource/content";}

  var terms = filterValue.split(' ');
  visibleLinks = allLinks.filter(function(link) {
      for (var termI = 0; termI < terms.length; ++termI) {
        var term = terms[termI];
        if (term.length != 0) {
          var expected = (term[0] != '-');
          if (!expected) {
            term = term.substr(1);
            if (term.length == 0) {
              continue;
            }
          }
          var found = (-1 !== link.indexOf(term));
          if (found != expected) {
            return false;
          }
        }
      }
      return true;
    });
}

function ExLinks(){
tempLinks = visibleLinks;
chrome.tabs.create({url: "chrome://newtab", active: false, index: 0}, function(tab){
        index = 0;
        //for (var index in tempLinks){
            chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: tempLinks[index], highlighted: false});
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: 'send_links.js', allFrames: true});
            //tempLinks[index] = visibleLinks[0];

        //}
        //visibleLinks = tempLinks;
        showLinks();
    });


}

// Add links to allLinks and visibleLinks, sort and show them.  send_links.js is
// injected into all frames of the active tab, so this listener may be called
// multiple times.

//chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(links) {
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
  console.assert(port.name == "links_port");
  port.onMessage.addListener(function(links) {
  for (var index in links) {
    allLinks.push(links[index]);
  }
  allLinks.sort();
  visibleLinks = allLinks;
  if(count == 0){
  filterLinks();
  count++;
  ExLinks();
  }
  else{
  //filterLinks();
  }
  showLinks();
  });
});

// Set up event handlers and inject send_links.js into all frames in the active
// tab.
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('toggle_all').onchange = toggleAll;
  document.getElementById('download0').onclick = downloadCheckedLinks;
  document.getElementById('download1').onclick = downloadCheckedLinks;

  chrome.runtime.connect();

  chrome.windows.getCurrent(function (currentWindow) {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, windowId: currentWindow.id},
                      function(activeTabs) {
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(
        activeTabs[0].id, {file: 'send_links.js', allFrames: true});
    });
  });
};
```

send_links.js :

```
// Copyright (c) 2012 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

// Send back to the popup a sorted deduped list of valid link URLs on this page.
// The popup injects this script into all frames in the active tab.

var links = [].slice.apply(document.getElementsByTagName('a'));
links = links.map(function(element) {
  // Return an anchor's href attribute, stripping any URL fragment (hash '#').
  // If the html specifies a relative path, chrome converts it to an absolute
  // URL.
  var href = element.href;
  var hashIndex = href.indexOf('#');
  if (hashIndex >= 0) {
    href = href.substr(0, hashIndex);
  }
  return href;
});

links.sort();

// Remove duplicates and invalid URLs.
var kBadPrefix = 'javascript';
for (var i = 0; i < links.length;) {
  if (((i > 0) && (links[i] == links[i - 1])) ||
      (links[i] == '') ||
      (kBadPrefix == links[i].toLowerCase().substr(0, kBadPrefix.length))) {
    links.splice(i, 1);
  } else {
    ++i;
  }
}

//chrome.extension.sendRequest(links);
var port = chrome.runtime.connect({name: "links_port"});
port.postMessage(links);
```